# Hide Show Button - Minor logic issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button, checkbox

I am a novice in jquery, I have recently built a form with few check boxes, once they are all checked it shows the submit button, two things happens when you check a checkbox.

1. the label changes colour
2. the checkbox swaps image

The form works well. I notice a minor bug in the form, if you click quicky for a repeated number of times on the label or checkbox it confuses the form and the label and checkbox doesnt change together. Please see a working version of the form.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6FhSD/

I think only a minor logic change would do the trick any help would be highly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give something like

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function(e) {
         $(this).next().toggleClass("active");   
});
```

a try.  Its more succinct and hopefully shouldn't suffer from the sync issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/benashby/CQ4nv/